# Java - Create anonymous Exception subclass with a certain name

Tags: java, android, crashlytics, byte-buddy, crashlytics-android

We're using Fabric / Crashlytics for sending non-crash issues to their servers and later checking out the logs and stacktraces.

Unfortunately, the Crashlytics API requires to use a different Exception subclass instance for different issue types. (In the iOS SDK, you can simply use a string for different issue types, but in the Android version, you can't).

```
public static void craslyticsRecordError(String issueType, String errorMsg)
{
    Exception e = new Exception(issueType + "-" + errorMsg);
    Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

Now we have quite a few different issue types, that we also dynamically define at runtime (build together from string parts). So the questions is, is it possible with some Java Vodoo / Hacks (reflection?) to create a subclass at runtime with a certain name (the name of the string that we use as the issue type) and create and instance from it.

Is this somehow possible?

---

I'm now fiddling with ByteBuddy, trying to get it to work - but I'm stuck at getting my dynamic class call the superclass constructor correctly. Also I'm not quite sure if I'm allowed to cast to Exception later on.

---

Thanks to Rafael Winterhalter I'm one step further into getting this thing to work ;) I've tried exactly the you provided:

```
public static void craslyticsRecordError(String issueType, String errorMsg)
{
    Class<? extends Exception> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Exception.class)
            .name(issueType)
            .make()
            .load(Fabric.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded();
    try
    {
        Exception e = dynamicType.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(errorMsg);

        GameLog.d("[Fabric] Inner Exception: " + e);
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        Exception e = new Exception(issueType + "-" + errorMsg);
        GameLog.d("[Fabric] ERROR ONE");
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and now I'm facing this runtime exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.NoOpClassFileTransformer
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.<init>(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:136)
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.of(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:187)
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ByteArrayClassLoader.load(ByteArrayClassLoader.java:212)
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default$WrappingDispatcher.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:285)
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.loading.ClassLoadingStrategy$Default.load(ClassLoadingStrategy.java:120)
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.TypeResolutionStrategy$Passive.initialize(TypeResolutionStrategy.java:79)
     at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Default$Unloaded.load(DynamicType.java:4376)
     at org.utils.Fabric.craslyticsRecordError(Fabric.java:47)
     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

---

After now using this Android-specific code:

```
Class<? extends Exception> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(Exception.class)
        .name(issueType)
        .make()
        .load(Fabric.class.getClassLoader(), AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
        .getLoaded();
```

and using the Android-specific gradle compile line:

```
compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-android:1.7.3'
```

I'm still facing the same runtime Exception as before.

Comment: Is this what you need? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259421/java-creating-a-subclass-dynamically

Comment: This looks very good, I'm currently trying to get ByteBuddy to run, but I'm a bit stuck at having my dynamic class call the constructor of it's superclass, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Byte Buddy copies the constructors of its super class. In your case, it copies all `Exception` constructors and you can generate an exception like this:

```
Class<? extends Exception> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Exception.class)
  .name(issueType)
  .make()
  .load(Fabric.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
  .getLoaded();

 Exception e = dynamicType.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(errorMsg);
```

Comment: Thank you! That brought me a good step further! It's great that you're active here! Unfortunately, I'm now facing a runtime exception when running the code (see my edit above). Do you have any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: You are using Android, in this case use the AndroidClassLoadingStrategy in the byte-buddy-android project.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've changed it (see Edit) and I'm still facing the same runtime exception. Any more ideas? ;)

Comment: You are using the same strategy as before, you just access the default strategy via the subclass. You need to instantiate the android class loading strategy yourself.

Comment: Thank you, it does work work. For the 'private directoy' in the constructor, I just used some directory in the app's file dirs - I hope that's alright. I'd also like to add a specific method with some code...but I'll fiddle a bit - maybe opening another question if I don't make it. Thanks a lot so far!

Comment: It needs to be application private to pass Androids sandbox security checks but if it works, its good as it is.

Comment: Ps: make sure to cache the generated types.

Comment: Yep, it's application private thanks! How do you mean Cache? What do I need to do for that and why is it important?

Comment: Rather reuse classes as Byte Buddy will recreate them. Have a look at the TypeCache. Class creation is expensive.